# Why is keypad white with some emulators and what I want (black) on my device and some emulators?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

Here's a picture from the Android Studio 1.1.0 emulator (my device matches the one on the left):

[image]

Here's how I'm requesting the keypad (I have only numeric input):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Does this guarantee that my app will have white keypad (WITH ALL CAPS ON BUTTONS) on some actual devices? (That's a sorry looking screen that I've gotten on other emulators, too!)

How do I guarantee the "stealth" (gray keypad) look?

Comment: The keypad is derived from the currently set keyboard app. Over time the design has changed, so that it now is white (following Material Design rules). To force a specific design, you need to code that keypad into your app, so that it is not the keyboard app, that is used for entering digits.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this guarantee that my app will have white keypad (WITH ALL CAPS ON BUTTONS) on some actual devices?

No.

> How do I guarantee the "stealth" (gray keypad) look?

Write your own input method editor. Or, do not allow text input.

Input method editors are written by programmers. Those programmers are free to implement their input method editors however they want.

As a result, you have:

- [input method editors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard&hl=en) that can use third-party themes, added by users
- [input method editors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.access_company.graffiti) with no keys at all
- and so on

Not to mention that on devices with physical keyboards, no "soft keyboard" will usually appear.